# PouchDB uncaught exception: Invalid adapter

Tags: pouchdb

I am new to javascript and pouchdb. I made a simple html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="js/pouch.alpha.js"></script>
        <title>New Web Project Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>New Web Project Page</h1>
        <script>
            Pouch('idb://test', function(err, db) {
                // Use db to call further functions
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I downloaded the pouch.alpha.js file and placed it into the "js" folder.

I just want to try the first example from the pouchdb.com website to create a database but Firefox>Tools>Web Developer>Error console gives me the error:

> uncaught exception: Invalid adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of firefox have you got installed? I just copied your exact test and it works for me with Firefox 16

Comment: well.. i just tried Chromium and it seems to be working.. So I guess something is wrong with my Firefox.. maybe one of my plugins? anyway I can do the job with Chromium for now. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I have Firefox 16.0.1 on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. Both give the same error.